# YouTrackSharp: can't get it to work

Tags: c#, youtrack, youtracksharp

Trying to open an issue from a C# app.

Few issues:

1) UPDATE: I realize it only supports .NET **Standard** 1.3 = Framework 4.6; So no issue here.

2) I install version 2.0.31 (and less) - When I try to set up a connection, it says "Method not allowed":

```
var connection = new Connection("xxxx.myjetbrains.com", 80, false, "youtrack");
connection.Authenticate("xxxxx", "xxxxxx");
var issueManagement = new IssueManagement(connection);
dynamic issue = new Issue();
issue.Assignee = "xxxxx";
issue.ProjectShortName = "CV";
issue.Type = "Bug";
issue.Summary = "Test";
issue.Description = "Testing 1 2 3 ...";
issueManagement.CreateIssue(issue);
```

connection.Authenticate throws the error.

3) If I don't specify other parameters in Connection  and leave only the basic url, I get the following error (again in connection.Authenticate):

> For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable
>   DTD processing set the DtdProcessing property on XmlReaderSettings to
>   Parse and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create method.

Can't seem to find much info on this online. Anyone has any idea what to do?

Comment: Ask **one** question per 'question'.  See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post

Comment: I have one issue - it's not working. I'm trying 3 possible ways to solve it and give the information here.

Comment: Then perhaps you should edit the part of the question where you say you have a "few issues" and then go on to describe three separate issues?

Comment: @Amy have you ever worked with YouTrackSharp? Or just YouTrack for that matter?

Comment: 2.x branch is abandoned long ago: "Be aware that these older branches are frozen and bug fixes nor new feature development is done on them.". I'd use 3.x if I were you. As for the error, it seems that you're trying access cloud YouTrack via plain http port 80. This is not going to work, please use https:// urls and port 443 instead.

Answer (score 1):

the 1.3 refers to *.NETStandard* - NOT .Net Framework.  These are not the same thing.

You need .Net Framework 4.6 or up for .Net Standard 1.3 compatibility.

See here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

I'd go directly to jetbrains for the other parts...

Comment: Yes, just realized the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else getting stuck:

my YouTrack account was like this:

https://mycompanyname.myjetbrains.com/youtrack

Since it uses SSL (i.e. https) I had to mark the SSL parameter true instead of false, and mark port 443 instead of 80. Also I had to add the "youtrack" as a parameter. So the end result looks like this:

```
var connection = new Connection("xxxx.myjetbrains.com", 443, true, "youtrack");
connection.Authenticate("xxxx@xxxx.xxx", "xxxx");
```

I only had to do this in v.2, as I mentioned, v.3.0.0+ has working examples in their blog.